# GATE jape rule annotate only Token kind word not working

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, gate

Hi I am trying to parse text from doc or pdf file. Whenever I try to annotate using :

`Phase: MyPhase
Input:Token SpaceToken
Options: control = appelt
Rule:MyRule
Priority:10
(
{Token.kind == "word"}
):abc
-->
:abc.ABC = {kind = "abc"}`

It is not annotating each Token of kind word as ABC annotation similar to  Token annotation.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is** annotating each `Token` of kind word as `ABC` annotation similar to `Token` annotation. A sample document annotated by the `JAPE` rule is attached bellow. Note the green annotations covering all the tokens except numbers and punctuation.

[image: <code>A sample document annotated by the JAPE rule.</code>]